# Linq Group by converted to SQL DISTINCT

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm using entity framework 6.1.1 with SQL Server CE 3.5/4.0. The following linq query with group by is converted into an sql query with distinct.

Linq:

```
var motorDesignQuery = from motor in context.Motors
                group motor by motor.Design
                into design
                select design.Key;
```

Converted into SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Distinct1].[Design] AS [Design]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Extent1].[Design] AS [Design]
    FROM [Motor] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Distinct1]
```

The result of the query with GROUP BY or DISTINCT is in this case the same, but DISTINCT is killing my performance. Can I force the entity framework to generate SQL with GROUP BY?

Comment: This might be one of those cases where you should use a stored procedure. For performance reasons, I usually have a few stored procedures in my solution for certain situations (typically bulk inserts and predicated updates).

Comment: If you don't want to use a stored procedure, you could always try writing a command interceptor and massage the SQL before sending it to the server, but it's a bit of an advanced feature.

Comment: I switched to Linq2SQL. It generates SQL with GROUP BY as expected.

Comment: @listenreich totally sucks that you had to use something else here to handle functionality that EF should.